# How to Add a custom Login module to WebLogic application?

Tags: authentication, weblogic, jaas

I have an webservice that valide the user and return the roles and I write an custom Jaas Login Module for it. 
How can I use this module in Weblogic(and webcenter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, if anyone has the same problem must take into account:

- The Principals in the JaaS must extend WLSUser or use WLSUserImp
- You must create a mbeantype, and put it in server/lib/mbeantypes
- Configure the authentication provider
  in the Weblogic console.